# The lenS>lenR always gives a segmentation error what is even wrong?

Tags: c

I am currently grappling with a challenging issue in my C programming project, and I am seeking some guidance to overcome a specific problem. The crux of the matter lies in a condition where I compare the lengths of two strings, `lenS` and `lenR`. Despite my meticulous implementation, the `lenS > lenR` condition doesn't seem to function as expected. I have scrutinized my code thoroughly, ensuring that I have accurately calculated the lengths of both strings and verified the logic behind the comparison. However, despite my efforts, I am unable to identify the root cause of this discrepancy. I have considered potential issues such as memory allocation, string termination, or loop control, but none seem to provide a resolution. At this point, I am reaching out for assistance and insights from the programming community to shed light on possible explanations or debugging strategies. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has expertise in C programming, your assistance in pinpointing the source of this `lenS > lenR` condition malfunction would be immensely valuable in helping me move forward with my project. Any advice, code snippets, or suggestions to troubleshoot and rectify this issue would be greatly appreciated.

My code attempts to replace a specified substring with a replacement string in a larger string.

When the replacement string is shorter than the search string, I get a segmentation fault instead of a string with the search string replaced by the replace string.

Here is my [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15BXdTSyhxbb_GyQ7yBLI6mcLH6oJF4uP/view?usp=sharing):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    char Mstr[200], Sstr[30], Rstr[30];
    int found, lenM, lenS, lenR, k, m, i, j, l, occ = 0;
    printf("Enter the string:");
    gets(Mstr);
    printf("Enter the sub string:");
    gets(Sstr);
    printf("Enter the replacing string:");
    gets(Rstr);
    lenM = strlen(Mstr);
    lenS = strlen(Sstr);
    lenR = strlen(Rstr);
    //printf("%d %d", lenM, sizeof(Mstr));

    if (lenS == lenR) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= lenM - lenS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lenR; j++) {
                if (Mstr[i + j] == Sstr[j])
                    found = 1;
                else {
                    found = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                for (int m = 0; m < lenR; m++)
                    Mstr[m + i] = Rstr[m];
            }  
        }
    }
    else if (lenS > lenR) {
        int diff = lenR - lenS;
        for (int i = 0; i <= lenM - lenS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lenS; j++) {
                if (Mstr[i + j] == Sstr[j]) {   
                    found = 1;
                    k = i + j;
                } else {
                    found = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }  
            
            if (found == 1) {
                printf("BLAH");
                int diff = lenS - lenR;
                printf("\n%d", diff);
                for (k = i, m = 0; m < lenR; k++, m++)
                    Mstr[k] = Rstr[m];
                for (; Mstr[k] != '\0'; k++)
                    Mstr[k] = Mstr[k + 1];
                lenM -= diff;
            }
            Mstr[k] = '\0';
        }
    }
    else if (lenR > lenS) {
        int diff = lenR - lenS;
        for(int i = 0; i <= lenM - lenS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lenS; j++) {
                if (Mstr[i + j] == Sstr[j]) {   
                    found = 1;
                    k = i + j;
                } else{
                    found = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }           
            if (found) {
                occ++;
                for (int h = 0; h < diff; h++) {             
                    for (l = lenM; l > k; l--)
                        Mstr[l + 1] = Mstr[l];
                    lenM++;
                    Mstr[lenM + diff * occ] = '\0';    
                }
                for (int m = 0; m < lenR; m++)
                    Mstr[m + i] = Rstr[m];
            }   
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe new string is:%s", Mstr);
}
```

Comment: No, we are not going to debug your program residing on a remote service.  Questions here must be self contained.  For debugging questions, a major part of that is that the question contains a [mre] demonstrating the issue, in the question itself.

Comment: in the `if (lenS > lenR)` case, the final loop should be `while ((Mstr[k] = Mstr[k + diff]) != '\0') k++;`  For the last case `if (lenR > lenS)`, there is no need for nested loops: just copy `Mstr[i..lenM]` to `Mstr[i+diff, lenM+diff]` and increment `lenM += diff` before copying the replacement string.  Also make sure you increment `i` by `lenR` in case of replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Use *functions* and standard library. If you do not want to use the standard library simply reimplement those functions.

In real code, you should check for error conditions like NULL pointers passed. I skipped it for the sake of simplicity

```
// This function replaces the first occurrence of 'needle' with 'replacement' in the 'haystack' string.
int strreplace(char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *replacement)
{
    // Calculate the lengths of the 'needle,' 'replacement,' and 'haystack' strings.
    size_t needleLen = strlen(needle);
    size_t replacementLen = strlen(replacement);
    size_t haystackLen = strlen(haystack);
    char *pos;

    // Check if 'needle' is found in 'haystack.'
    if ((pos = strstr(haystack, needle)))
    {
        // Calculate the number of characters to move after 'pos' to make space for 'replacement.'
        size_t charsToMove = haystackLen - (pos - haystack) + 1;

        // Move characters after 'needle' to make enough space for 'replacement.'
        memmove(pos + replacementLen, pos + needleLen, charsToMove);

        // Copy 'replacement' into the 'haystack' at 'pos.'
        memcpy(pos, replacement, replacementLen);
    }

    // Return '1' if 'needle' was found and replaced, or '0' if 'needle' was not found.
    return !!pos;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[100] = "test dog vampire nothing";
    
    strreplace(str, "dog", "bulldog");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    strreplace(str, "vampire", "cat");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    strreplace(str, "nothing", "");
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

also use the correct types for sizes

To replace all occurrences

```
char *replaceAll(char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *replacement)
{
    while(strreplace(haystack, needle, replacement));
    return haystack;
}
```

(note that it will not work if you try to replace "dog" with "bulldog" - try to find out why)